# Trying to find subset of string in a list of string

Tags: string, list, vb.net, substring, contains

I'm trying to find a substring in a list of string in vb.net. I'm not understanding why this doesn't work after lots of looking around on here and other places. I wrote a simple example below. I feel like I should be able to use a wild card but nothing seems to do the trick.

```
Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim StringList As New List(Of String) From {"book1", "book2", "book3"}
        Dim st As String = StringList(0)

        'this block of code works
        If st.Contains("book") Then
            Console.WriteLine("This works!")
            Console.ReadLine()
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("This doesn't work!")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If

        'this block of code does not work
        If StringList.Contains("book") Then
            Console.WriteLine("This works!")
            Console.ReadLine()
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("This doesn't work!")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If

    End Sub
```

I tried using a wild card. I feel like there is a better solution than iterating through the list.

Comment: [IList.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.contains?view=net-8.0) "Determines whether the IList contains a specific value.", not whether the IList's items contain a specific value. "...this method uses the collection's objects' Equals and CompareTo methods on item to determine whether item exists.", so it's looking for string equality, not string contains

Comment: You can't avoid iteration. All the LINQ solutions and String.Join will iterate the list. The most performant option would be a foreach, for, while, etc. which stops once it finds a match, so you don't iterate the entire list. @idle_mind answer using `Any` will similarly stop searching at the first match. Syntactically, it is clear and concise.

Comment: So I did get it to work by using a foreach, however it was really ugly considering it had to go inside an already ugly collection of if and orelse statements. I ended up changing to use the answer below. Plus it gave me something else to read about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I feel like there is a better solution than iterating through the
> list.

Well, that really is what needs to happen. You can, however, use the [.Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0) function and pass it a [Lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions), and it will do the iterating for you:

```
If StringList.Any(Function(s) s.Contains("book")) Then
    Console.WriteLine("This works!")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("This doesn't work!")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Idle_Mind's answer seems right; you must iterate, and you can have the iteration done by the compiler. But I would rather use `String.Join` like this:

```
If String.Join(",", StringList).Contains("book") Then
```

It seems clearer to me because of following the way my mind works.

Note that if you don't include the separator with this method then you could get incorrect results, if you had a couple of strings next to each other like `bonobo` and `okra`.

I'm not sure which would be faster in the long run.

Comment: What if you are searching for "1,b"? String.Join will also iterate. OP's wrong about his feeling `I feel like there is a better solution than iterating through the list.`

Comment: @djv, then you should pick a different delimiter, something more obscure. Or even include multiple characters unlikely to go together. I assumed from the data provided that only alphanumeric characters could be in the data.

Comment: I mean, sure, but you can't guarantee it will work 100% if the search string is not hard-coded as "book". This is still an interesting approach but you already started to note its inherent flaws.